# Materialize css slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

hey guys am using materialize css for my site. when i insert the code for the slider it only shows a grey background. here is my code:

```
<div class="slider">
<ul class="slides">
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1">
    <div class="caption center-align">
      <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
      <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2">
    <div class="caption left-align">
      <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
      <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8):

Your code is not working since you have missed `jQuery Initialization`. In your `JS` file include following `script` or  add following `<script>` tag in your `html` page.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.slider').slider({full_width: true});
   });
</script>
```

Following is a full working code in single `html` page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

    <head>
        <title>Slider</title>
        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
        <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--your code start-->
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1">
                    <div class="caption center-align">
                        <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2">
                    <div class="caption left-align">
                        <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--your code end-->

        <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

        <!--Materializecss Slider-->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.slider').slider({full_width: true});
            });
        </script>         
    </body>

</html>
```